# Is it possible to inherit from a template base class but not to make the derived class a template as well?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I tried to inherit from a template base class but I get several errors because my derived class is no template class. I also don't want it to be, I just want to share some variables and let the derived class implement them.

```
//base.h
template <typename T>
class Base
{

public:
     explicit Base(QWidget *parent);
    ~Base();

protected:
    QList<T*>* list;
    T* selectedObject;

};

//base.cpp
#include "base.h"

template <typename T>
Base<T>::Base(QWidget* parent)
{

}

template <typename T>
Base<T>::~Base()
{

}


//derived.h
namespace Ui
{
    class Derived;
}

class Derived: public QWidget, public Base<MyType>
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Derived(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Derived();

private:
    Ui::Derived*ui;
};

//derived.cpp
Derived::Dervied(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent), Base<Mytype>(parent)
{
    list = new QList<MyType*>();
}
```

So I e.g. want to implement this Qlist from the base class but with a specific type parameter like MyType. 
I haven't worked with templates in combination with inheritance before in c++ and I tried several things but they didn't work out.

**EDIT**
So, I tried like dtbeaver explained below but then I get following error message:
undefined reference to 'Base::Base()'.
I get this for the constructor and deconstructor

Comment: Yes it's possible. What didn't work for you specifically?

Comment: It's possible, and I am making _extreme_ use of it in my current project (which thankfully uses gtkmm rather than Qt - controversial.) You say it doesn't work, but _how_? Is there an error reported? What is it? "I tried several things but they didn't work out." **In what way**?

Comment: `Base` doesn't have default constructor in your case. Unrelated to the fact it is  template btw.

Comment: `base.cpp` is suspicious too.

Comment: base.cpp constructor is filled in my original example but i didn't want to put this is in as it does not matter for my question. 
The errors I got were endlessly going on with every correction i made so i didn't want to post them. I just wanted someone to tell me the basic principle of how to do this and that's why I made a big abstraction of my real example and provided in a way for others to understand what i want to do. 

The right answer is down below, it is because i am separating header and implementation

Comment: You forget rename of base.cpp to base.hpp and  #include "base.hpp" to derived.cpp

Comment: did this...still get this error message

Answer (score 9):

**Yes**, it's totally possible but you may want to keep an alias of the base type.

Example

```
class Derived: public QWidget, public Base<MyType>
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    using BaseType = Base<Mytype>;  //alias, will be useful someday
    explicit Derived(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Derived();

private:
    Ui::Derived*ui;
};
```

**Secondly**, during template instatiation, all definitions must be visible to the compiler. You *can't really have the regular* separate header and implementation files for templates, **You can with a few extra techniques**. Please see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 3):

Template classes declaration and implementation **can** be splitted in separated files, but you must include both in place where you using template.

And you have syntax errors in your base template implementation:

```
//base.h
template <typename T>
class Base
{

public:
     explicit Base(QWidget *parent);
    ~Base();

protected:
    QList<T*>* list;
    T* selectedObject;

};

//base.hpp
#include "base.h"

template <typename T>
Base<T>::Base(QWidget* parent)
{

}

template <typename T>
Base<T>::~Base()
{

}


//derived.h
namespace Ui
{
    class Derived;
}

#include "base.h"

class Derived: public QWidget, public Base<MyType>
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Derived(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Derived();

private:
    Ui::Derived*ui;
};

//derived.cpp
#include "base.hpp"
Derived::Dervied(QWidget* parent) : QWidget(parent), Base<Mytype>()
{
    list = new QList<MyType*>();
}
```

and don't forget to use #pragma once or guard definitions